# login to a webpage using Powershell 7

Tags: powershell, invoke-webrequest, powershell-7.0

I am trying to re-write my code that works with powershell 5.1 but it doesn't work with powershell 7.x
so this is the simplified code that works with PS5.1:

```
$url = "mysite.com/login"
$r=Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -UseDefaultCredentials -SessionVariable RequestForm 
$fields = $r.Forms[0].Fields
$fields['field_id1'] = 'myusername'
$fields['field_id2'] = 'secretPass'
$fields['__EVENTTARGET'] = 'btnLogin'
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -WebSession $RequestForm -Method POST -Body $fields -ContentType 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
```

but this code doesn't work with powershell 7.x
I am trying to get this code to work in Azure Function App, but it only takes powershell 7

so, the issues i am having is Invoke-WebRequest doesn't return Forms[0].Fields
how would i rewrite this code to submit the username and password with powershell 7

Comment: Inspect the data that you post when submitting the form in the browser debugger or a tool like fiddler, then reconstruct the reconstruct the request. That's how I always do this kind of things.

Comment: If you run the commands one at at time what does $r show you? If I look at Invoke-WebRequest for v7, it tells me it outputs a BasicHtmlWebResponseObject, but that doesn't list a "Forms" property? v5 used to output a HtmlWebResponseObject, which did have a Forms property. See this link and change the version at the top left: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-7.1